# Using R for Image Data

Tags: r, image

I have been tasked with using R to analyze fluorescence in images. I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction, or let me know if this is not possible.

Comment: Your question is far too vague for Stack Overflow's format. Please consider adding more details.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please include a reproducible question as suggested here [How to ask good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) & [Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) include your data (as a dataframe object or use dput("data"), the code you have tried and your expected output. This will make it more likely to get a good answer.Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices.